# Select ROW if not in another query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

I have this query :

```
query 1 = 
SELECT emp.employeId,emp.nom,emp.prenom,msg.note,msg.quelleDate, emp.remarques, emp.autonome, embauche.actif as embaucheActif, embauche.embId, 'M' as source 
FROM employes emp 
LEFT JOIN messages msg ON msg.employeId = emp.employeId 
LEFT JOIN embauche ON embauche.employeId = emp.employeId 
WHERE emp.actif = 1 
AND msg.quelleDate BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-31' 

UNION 

SELECT emp.employeId,emp.nom,emp.prenom,msg.note,msg.quelleDate, emp.remarques, emp.autonome, embauche.actif as embaucheActif, embauche.embId, 'A' as source 
FROM employes emp 
LEFT JOIN messagesautre msg ON msg.employeId = emp.employeId 
LEFT JOIN embauche ON embauche.employeId = emp.employeId 
WHERE emp.actif = 1 
AND msg.quelleDate BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-31' 

ORDER BY nom,prenom,quelleDate
```

And this query

```
query2 = select nom,prenom from employes where actif = 1;
```

I'm trying to get all employeId from `query2` that don't appear in `query1`

I have tried with

```
select employeId,nom,prenom from employes where actif = 1 AND employeId in ( query1 );
```

but of course that doesn't work because `query1` return more than 1 columns

Is is possible to do that with a MySQL query? or i'll have to write the PHP algorithm to do this??

Comment: Could you provide table structure and sample data? It might help solve your question.

Comment: See my edited post for link

Comment: thank you. I had already created something myself. My French is however not that great so I needed to do some guesswork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it to simple to do this:

```
select nom,prenom from employes AS emp 
LEFT JOIN embauche AS emb  
ON emp.employeID = emb.employeID
LEFT JOIN messages AS msg
ON emp.employeID = msg.employeID
where actif <> 1
AND msg.quelleDate NOT BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-31';
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE employes (
  employeId int auto_increment primary key,
  nom varchar(30),
  prenom varchar(30),
  remarques longtext,
  autonome longtext
  );

CREATE TABLE messages (
  messagesID int auto_increment primary key,
  employeId int,
  quelleDate DATE,
  note longtext

  );

CREATE TABLE embauche(
  embId int auto_increment primary key,
  employeID int,
  actif int
  );

INSERT INTO employes (nom,prenom,remarques,autonome)
VALUES ("hollande", "francois", "24th President of France", "?"),
("Sarkozy", "Nicolas", "23th President of France", "?");


INSERT INTO messages (employeId,quelleDate,note)
VALUES (1, now(),"jlkjlkahkjhkj"),
(2,NOW() - INTERVAL 365 DAY,"jlkjlkahkjkjjhajhjheuioueoijhkj");


INSERT INTO embauche (employeId,actif)
VALUES (2, 2),
(1,1);
```

[Demo sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84eb5/1)

Comment: @PL Audet I didn't explain it in my answer but what I did was basically turn the where clause around. So, were your first query wanted a positive I turned into a negative. Glad that I was able to help you.

Comment: Good thinking.  I couldn't figure out why the question looked for actives in one place and not actives in the other. I guess that was the problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I had the same problem in the beginning. That was the reason that I start my answer with "Is it to simple".

Answer (score 2):

Your condition in the second query on a table in the first query.  Are there duplicate names and first names in the employee table?  If not, you can just add the following to each of the `where` clauses:

```
and emp.Active = 1
```

If `Actif` and `Active` are the same, then you will never get any rows.

A more general approach would be to add the following to the where clause:

```
and not exists (select 1 from employes emp2 where emp2.prenom = emp.prenom and emp2.nom = emp.prenom)
```

Comment: my bad, actif and active are supposed to be the same... i will fix this.

Comment: I would suggest a 'more general' approach as follows: SELECT * FROM (query2) x LEFT JOIN (query1) y ON y.id = x.id WHERE y.id IS NULL;

Comment: Both method gave me the exact same result :S i'm still missing some employee.

Comment: I'd like to help. Unfortunately I cannot replicate this finding without subtly bending the laws of physics!